# Refresh the page automatically and Click button to refresh are not working (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, html

I have two problems. it doesn't work at all. Do I need jQuery library version for refresh page automatically and click button to refresh page manually?

Here are my code.

```
//for refresh automatically in 25 seconds
    <script>
            function ReloadPage() {
               location.reload();
            };

            $(document).ready(function() {
              setTimeout("ReloadPage()", 2500); .
            });
        </script>

// for refresh manually using button click
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#btnReload').click(function() {
                location.reload();
            });
        });
        </script>
```

HTML for button is

```
<input div="btnReload" type="submit" value="Update">
```

Any idea guys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use jQuery for this. You can use raw Javascript like so:

```
HTML:

<input type="submit" value="Update" onClick="ManualRefresh();">
```

**Javascript:**

```
<script>
    setInterval(function() {
        window.location.reload();
    }, 10000); 

    function ManualRefresh(){
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey @Lodder thank you for make the button works. By the way, `setInterval` is to update automatically? 10000 is for how many seconds? What number I should put for every minute?

Comment: Yes, wait a moment. Needs to take time to accept this answer :)

Comment: @Lodder Sorry I am not much familiar with this. Could you please tell me how to add this script to webpage where we want to autoclick the button?